# How to handle error dialog boxes in ActionScripts 3

Tags: actionscript-3, animate-cc

I write some code to check an XML from a URL, it works when Internet connection exist, but when i manually disable internet for test an Error dialog box show, i coudn't handle it with `try() catch()`.

```
try {
    var myXML: XML = new XML();
    var XML_URL: String = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B5pkl4TJ7V0OTFBPanUyMWQxUnM";
    var myXMLURL: URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL);
    var myLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL);
    myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);

    function xmlLoaded(event: Event): void {
        myXML = XML(myLoader.data);
        trace("LOCK CODE: " + myXML.LOCK);
        if (myXML.LOCK == 0) {
            gotoAndStop(71);
        };
    }
} catch (e: Error) {
    gotoAndStop(71);
    trace("FAILED TO CHECK LOCK.");
} finally {
    gotoAndStop(71);
    trace("FAILED TO CHECK LOCK.");
}
```

[image]

**How can i hide this dialog from user?**

Comment: add an [URLLoader event listener](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#eventSummary) for IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR e.g. ```myLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
            trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
        }
```. You should handle all events as good measure anyway (e.g. security error, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your quick and useful answer.

Comment: Also, loading an URL is asynchronous, so your try-catch block is useless here.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza thinking to post as a answer maybe? It seems that solves the problem.

Comment: @coner just added as an answer as well

Answer (score 1):

Add an [URLLoader event listener](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#eventSummary) for IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR 
e.g.

```
myLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler); 

function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void { 
  trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event); 
}
```

You should handle all events as good measure anyway (e.g. security error, etc.) 
The [as3 docs example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#includeExamplesSummary) provides a helpful snippet

Ideally you would not only silently trace message, but hopefully display helpful feedback or placeholder content for the user to understand what to expect.